# Show Content Type Fields from a entity reference

Tags: views, entities

I have a content type which i have linked to another content type. For e.g.

- Companies (Content Type)
- Employees (Content Type)

When creating a new employee i have to say which company it works for so in the Field Type i chose "Entity Reference and chose Autocomplete as the widget".

Now i have created a view which shows a list of all the employees, in this view i can show the companies Name however i want to show the companies logo instead of the name.

How can i grab the fields from "Companies" and display them within the Employees VIEW?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the Parent info (Company) through Child nodes (Employee) you need to add the Relationship for the Entity Reference field that is connecting the child to the parent.

Once you add that Relaionship you will be able to add the fields from the Company CT. Those fields must use that Relationship to show the Company info, otherwise if you don't select the Relationship for a field it will show the original (Employee) info.

So after you add the Relationship for the Company ER field (that is on Employee CT), you will be able to add the Logo field to your Views, and that field will use the Relationship you've just added.

Comment: Thanks alot! i was adding the wrong relationship.